# Ant exec executable="cmd" with '-' issue

Tags: ant, cmd, exec

So I am trying to execute some git commands in the old  tag of ANT.

```
<exec executable="cmd" failonerror="true" dir = "D:\Test">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="git remote -v"/>
</exec>
```

But I get this error:
 [exec] error: unknown switch ` '
 [exec] usage: git remote [-v | --verbose]

If I execute any other commant that is not having '-' in it it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Put each argument of the `git` command in its own `<arg>` element:

```
<exec executable="cmd" failonerror="true" dir="D:\Test">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="git"/>
    <arg value="remote"/>
    <arg value="-v"/>
</exec>
```